# How can I make product suggestions to TLG?

Tags: lego-group

I'm sure lots of is have had ideas for products, parts, sets, themes or services that we'd like LEGO to produce. What are the best ways of proposing them to TLG, and of persuading them to take on our ideas?

The options of which I am already aware:

1. For **themes** and **individual sets**, you can make a proposal at [ideas.lego.com/](https://ideas.lego.com/), and if you get enough votes and TLG think your idea has sufficient commercial merit then it might be made into a set.
2. You could try to get with TLG and if you manage it, you might be able to influence them from within.

Is there anything else we can do?

Answer (score 2):

There is the LEGO Ambassador program too: http://aboutus.lego.com/en-us/lego-group/programs-and-visits/lego-ambassador

> **The mission of the LEGO Ambassadors is to** work together with the LEGO Group in all areas which concern the worldwide LEGO community and **be the voice of their respective LEGO User Group towards the LEGO Group.**

This means you should contact a LEGO User Group (preferably one in your area) and try to raise your suggestion to the group's Ambassador.